# Acessing css menu inside root directory

Tags: php, html, css

I have CSS menu in my root directory.I want to access CSS menu in other sub directories.But when i go to sub directory i couldn't go back from sub directory and couldn't access other sub directory.
inside one sub==>http://localhost/Web/category/category.php
When i'm inside "category" folder i couldn't access CSS menu in "Web" folder.It gives file path as http://localhost/Web/category/item/newform.php.My CSS menu is in Web folder and include it the files.How can i fix this??

```
<ul>
   <li class='has-sub' >
      <a href='#'><span>Category</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='category/category.php'><span>New Category</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'>
      <a href='#'><span>Item</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='item/newform.php'><span>Add New Item</span></a></li>
      </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please provide a snippet or a fiddle for us to understand and work on your problem!

Comment: Are you talking about links to pages, including css or including PHP in other PHP-files?

Comment: This is clearly not clear...

Comment: I have css menu in Web(root) folder.When i'm in sub folder category i couldn't access another sub folder called item.i already include css menu for both sub folders.It gives file path as http://localhost/Web/category/item/newform.php

Comment: 1. _"I have css menu"_ - are you talking about the css-files, html-markup or both? 2. _"When i'm in sub folder category i couldn't access another sub folder"_ - Here's where you really lost me. Access how? Are you trying to include the html-markup/php-file or are you trying to load the css-file using `<link href="...">`? Or are you simply asking about how to _link_ to files (using <a href=",,,") to other files in other sub folders?

Comment: ...and if the issue isn't with any PHP-code, please remove the PHP-tag.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% understanding the issue here but it sounds like it is a path issue. Try including the css file like this with the full path:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
```

You can also put in the full http path to the css file to see of that helps:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/styles/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

To gain access to a CSS folder (located in your root directory) from a sub-directory you'd include the link within a php file located in your root directory such as header.php.

**'header.php'**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

Then require the 'header.php' within your sub-directory file

**example:**

```
<?php require_once '../header.php'; ?>
```